# Runtime error using osm overpass query

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I installed overpass like described in
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install

and I cloned the db.

when I run a simple query I get the following error:

```
<query type="node">
<bbox-query n="51.0" s="50.9" w="6.9" e="7.0"/>
<has-kv k="amenity" v="pub"/>
</query>
<print/>
encoding remark: Your input starts with a tag but not the root tag.
Thus, a line with the datatype declaration and a line with the root tag
'osm-script' is added. This shifts line numbering by -2 line(s).

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>
The data included in this document is from ww.openstreetmap.org.
The data is made available under ODbL.
</note>
<meta osm_base=""/>

After 0h0m15s: in "query", part 1, on line 3.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Zlib_Inflate::Error'
what():  Zlib_Inflate: -3
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do you know how  I can solve this issue?

Comment: Try reporting your issue at https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API

Comment: 2 questions: which exact version did you install (link to download location please), and how did you clone the DB (i.e. where did you download the DB files from)?

It seems to me, you're trying to use database files, which have been created without Zlib compression enabled. However, the Overpass API version you're using requires Zlib.

Comment: I used this guide: (http://overpass-api.de/no_frills.html) cloned the db with the following command: **nohup bin/download_clone.sh --source=http://dev.overpass-api.de/api_drolbr/ --db-dir="db/" --meta=yes**

Comment: Ok, it seems that the clone files don't really match the 0.7.52 release. To resolve this, please get in touch with Roland via mail, see [this Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Developers_.2F_System_Administrators) page for details.

Comment: Did you get some feedback in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

The files I downloaded were corrupted, I re - downloaded them and compared with the published check - sums and all worked fine